# How to disable text-autocorrection for an UITextField or keyboard?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have a case where autocorrection NEVER makes any sense. It's incredibly annoying. Can I disable it for the UITextField?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

With Interface Builder you can disable "Correction" in the "Attributes" Tab in Inspector.

[image: Correction]

Programmaticaly you can use

```
UITextField* textfield = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Comment: Hello Audience, How we can enable the same option for NSTextfield (Mac app). Do you have any thoughts?